# How do I politely tell a student to take a shower?

Tags: interpersonal-issues

There's a student in my class who obviously has some serious body hygeine issues. To preface, this is a fairly packed class -- about 60 students in a small lecture room.  The class is about 2 hours long. The problem has been so bad that when the student comes up to ask a question the stench hits hard. The problem is so bad lately that in the past month, people will leave a seat distance away from this one person, even standing up for the entirety of the lecture just to avoid sitting next to this person when the only seats available are next to the person.

I don't know how to approach him and to ask that they take care of their body. Or will I be a prude if I do try to get him to shower? Maybe it's a unique body issue that he can't fix (unlikely), but I really want to solve this before exams come up, which are going to cause issues. No one has come up to talk to me privately about it but the problem is incredibly obvious.

What should I do?